# Как определить после какого символа заканчивается строка?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, richtextbox

Как определить после какого символа заканчивается строка?

Это Paragraph-> Inlines типа Run (это не обычная строка ):

```
12
34
```

Эти (выше) значения будет принимать completeTextRange.Text. Но запишет в одну строку 1234

```
foreach (Block r in text_rich.Document.Blocks)
            {                   
                if (r is Paragraph)
                {
                    foreach (Inline i in ((Paragraph)r).Inlines)
                    {
                        if (i is Run)
                        {
                            var completeTextRange = new TextRange(i.ContentStart, i.ContentEnd);

                            res.Append(completeTextRange.Text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, так:

```
foreach (Block r in text_rich.Document.Blocks)
{
    if (r is Paragraph)
    {
        foreach (Inline i in ((Paragraph)r).Inlines)
        {
            if (i is Run)
            {
                var completeTextRange = new TextRange(i.ContentStart, i.ContentEnd);
                res.Append(completeTextRange.Text);
            }
            else if (i is LineBreak)
            {
                // строка закончилась, делайте что хотите
                // например
                res.Append("\n");
            }
        }
        // абзац закончился, делайте что хотите, например
        res.Append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Оу точно, наверно это хотел увидеть автор.

Comment: этот код не выполняется `else if (i is LineBreak)
    {`

Comment: До условия else не доходит. Всегда Run выполняется

Comment: @codename0082016: Окей, тогда расскажите, как именно вы получаете такой текст в вашем `RichTextBox`. Это важно.

Comment: @codename0082016: У меня код работает правильно, значит, у вас текст получен по-другому.

Comment: Текст напечатан в richtextboxe. А как его правильно получать? Можно исходники?

Comment: @codename0082016: Напечатан вручную, пользователем, после запуска программы?

Comment: @codename0082016: И ещё, пользователя нажимает Enter или Ctrl-Enter?

Comment: вручную после запуска программы Enter

Comment: @codename0082016: Тогда у вас в первом `Paragraph`'е должно быть `12`, а хвост (`34`) — во втором `Paragraph`'е.

Comment: @codename0082016: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Используй символ переноса строки: `\n` (регулярное выражение).
Он сделает перенос на новую строку. (Если я правильно понял твой вопрос)

```
sting str = "12 \n"+ "34"
```